# Whitespace but non-space

Tags: python, character, special-characters

I have text type field in database. In this field I have text:

`T: Text value`

Problem is with sign between `T:` and `Text`. It is not space and I have problem with cut it. How can I check what character is it and cut it?

Comment: It might be a 'horizontal tab' for example. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character

Comment: You could try this : `re.sub(r'[^0-9a-zA-Z:]+',' ','T:__ Test').split(' ')`. This replaces all characters which are not `0-9`, `a-z`, `A-Z` or `:` with a space.  Then you can just split (or cut) it with space. If there are any other characters you don't want to be replaced just add them to the list

Answer (score 0):

*How can I check what character is it?*

```
python
Python 3.5.1 …
>>>
>>> import unicodedata
>>> astring='T: Text value'
>>> for x in astring: print( x, 'U\{:04x}'.format(ord(x)), unicodedata.name(x, '?'))
...
```

> ```
> T U\0054 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
> : U\003a COLON
>   U\00a0 NO-BREAK SPACE
> T U\0054 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
> e U\0065 LATIN SMALL LETTER E
> x U\0078 LATIN SMALL LETTER X
> t U\0074 LATIN SMALL LETTER T
>   U\0020 SPACE
> v U\0076 LATIN SMALL LETTER V
> a U\0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A
> l U\006c LATIN SMALL LETTER L
> u U\0075 LATIN SMALL LETTER U
> e U\0065 LATIN SMALL LETTER E
> ```